# Where should I throw custom exceptions and catch Exception object

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, exception

I am coding a Spring MVC, hibernate app. I can't decide where should I throw custom exceptions, what custom exceptions to throw and where to catch "Exception", in controller or service or DAO?

I tried to throw a custom exception in controller and service and catch "Exception" in the controller as the last catch block. But every time a custom exception is thrown, the last catch block( of Exception) catches it and throws CustomGenericException overriding the previous one.

//Controller

```
@PostMapping("/add/{user_id}/{book_id}")
public @ResponseBody
String addToCart(@PathVariable("user_id") Integer user_id,
                 @PathVariable("book_id") Integer book_id){
    try {
        return cartService.addBook(user_id, book_id);
    }
    catch (HibernateException | CannotCreateTransactionException dbException) {
        throw new DatabaseDownException("Database error. Could not connect at this time.");
    }
    catch (Exception ex){
        throw new CustomGenericException("Could not add book to cart at this time. Please try again later.");
    }
}
```

//Service

```
@Override
public String addBook(int user_id, int book_id) {
    if(bookDAO.getCount(book_id)>0) {
        Cart cart = new Cart(user_id, book_id);
        List<Cart> userCarts = cartDAO.getCart(user_id, 0);
        for (Cart c : userCarts) {
            if (c.getBook_id() == book_id) {
                return "Book already in cart!";
            }
        }
        List<Cart> issuedBooks =cartDAO.getCart(user_id, 1);
        for(Cart c:issuedBooks){
            if(c.getBook_id()==book_id){
                return "Book already issued. Can't add another to cart.";
            }
        }
        return cartDAO.addBookToCart(cart);
    }
    return "No more copies left. Please try again later.";
}
```

I want to know where should I throw exceptions, where to catch them and how to avoid custom thrown exceptions getting caught by last catch block.

Comment: Depends on many factors. For the last part, don't catch all exceptions if you don't want to handle all exceptions the same. If you want to handle 1 specific exception in another way, add a specific catch block for it (before the generic one)

Answer (score 0):

@aks If you want to throw checked exceptions than you should pass "cause" exception to constructor of exception on higher level (in this case the last one catch) because otherwide the cause information is lost. Core Exception class has constructor with cause parameter to pass. 
You can also try to use Controller Advice https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc
I hope I helped a little bit :)

Answer (score 0):

read about chained exception in Java [here](https://www.baeldung.com/java-chained-exceptions)

you are not wrapping exception object in your custom exception , that is why you feel like previous exception is getting overridden .